# Adobe Premiere: H.264 export results in black screen

Tags: premiere, adobe, export, premiere-pro

I am trying to export a 44 minute, 2.641 GB video on the latest version of adobe premiere 2023, but everytime I do, I get a video with a black screen. Note that I am exporting with Range: Source In/Out and no effects aside from cross dissolves.

[image: Export Settings 1]
[image: Export Settings 2]